# Alternative for 'delay' term in case count - not time - does matter

Tags: word-request, nouns

Let's say Bob asks Alice a question. If Alice does not answer the question Bob is posing now, but the question he posed earlier - how is this delay expressed?

Both the words 'lag' and 'delay' seem inappropriate here, as they are much more specific about time, and not about the time when the question was asked.

Comment: I can't think of a word for it, but here's a classic example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0C59pI_ypQ

Comment: I think you're making things difficult for yourself by supposing that words 'lag' and 'delay' are inappropriate because they're "much more specific about time". Both those terms (and probably others) can be used in contexts where actual "clock" times and durations are irrelevant (such as your context, where all that matters is the *sequence*). I know the collocation has specific technical connotations, but I'd be inclined to just say Alice and Bob are having an ***asynchronous conversation*** (where Alice's responses are "delayed" by one conversational "turn");

Comment: @FumbleFingers, it seems you've solved my problem by assuming I shouldn't search for alternative in the first place. Thank you. Still I think I should wait for complete answer if any.

Comment: I find it hard to believe Alice and Bob could actually have a "real time" interaction as described (if Alice's utterances really were "offset" like that, relative to the immediately-preceding utterance, she'd probably be of immense interest to neurologists and such, but it's hard to see how anyone could actually "converse" with her). But I do note that this is an inherent feature of what can happen with interactive text messaging (SMS, Whatsapp, web-based discussion forums) often ends up, so maybe there *is* a term for it.

Comment: Alice did answer his previous question. She took her time answering his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for example, you're talking about a series of *texts* in which you respond to someone's first text, even though new texts have come in, and then you respond to the next text, even as the other person responds to your first text, well ...  I don't think there is a name for it because it's so *ubiquitous* that it's *normal*.  Example:

> Alex: Hey, are you coming over to watch the game tonight?
>   Alex: By the way John says he can't make it, he's got the kids.
>   Alex: Oh and grab a six-pack on your way?  I'm low.
>   Brad: I'll be there, but probably late.  Who else is coming?
>   Alex: OK, that's fine, kickoff is at 6pm
>   Brad: Sorry about John, but family ya?  What kind of beer?
>   Alex: Sam and Rick said they'd come by.
>   Brad: Oh man Rick?
>   Brad: Dude is gonna talk the whole game.
>   Alex: Whatever.
>   Brad: Whatever?
>   Alex: Whatever kind of beer you want.
>   Alex: Yeah about Rick but Sam is bringing him so what ya gonna do?
>   Brad: K see you later on.

I'd call this a *disjointed* conversation, in which the questions and responses are *out of whack* but nevertheless comprehensible.

*Skewed* is also possible, or *jumbled*, or *discontinuous*, in which questions and answers *are flying all over the place*.

A technical person might call it an *asynchronous* conversation (as FumbleFingers suggested) which is accurate, but I don't think that would be meaningful to the average person.

However I would not call it *confused* or *incoherent* (or many of the other synonyms of *disjointed*) because the participants mostly understand each other even though the responses *don't match up* with the previous texts.

(Edit) More formally we could define this as a *lag* between *query* and *response*, which you could call a *delay* of some number of *conversational cycles*.  Anyone familiar with these terms (and how they relate to asynchronous communication) would easily understand what you mean.

Comment: I was looking for actual term to use in context with meaning "delay for two/ten iterations". As @FumbleFingers mentioned, such construction is totally valid. Would you mind mentioning it, so I can accept your answer?

Comment: @yurimz  ok, done. Be aware that if you are writing a formal paper on this phenomenon, the literature might already have a *formal* term for it.